# Spark Scala getting null pointer exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rasterframes

I'm trying to get mass elevation data from tiff image, I have a csv file. csv file contents latitude, longitude and other attributes also. Looping through csv file and getting latitude and longitude and calling elevation method, Code given below. Reference [RasterFrames extracting location information problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56913645/rasterframes-extracting-location-information-problem)

```
    package main.scala.sample

    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import org.locationtech.rasterframes._
    import org.locationtech.rasterframes.datasource.raster._
    import org.locationtech.rasterframes.encoders.CatalystSerializer._
    import geotrellis.raster._
    import geotrellis.vector.Extent
    import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

    object SparkSQLExample {

        def main(args: Array[String]) {

            implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local[*]").appName("RasterFrames")
            .withKryoSerialization.getOrCreate().withRasterFrames
            spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")


            import spark.implicits._

            val example = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/locationtech/rasterframes/develop/core/src/test/resources/LC08_B7_Memphis_COG.tiff"
            val rf = spark.read.raster.from(example).load()

            val rf_value_at_point = udf((extentEnc: Row, tile: Tile, point: Point) => {
              val extent = extentEnc.to[Extent]
              Raster(tile, extent).getDoubleValueAtPoint(point)
            })

            val spark_file:SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local[1]")
            .appName("SparkByExamples")
            .getOrCreate()

            spark_file.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

            println("spark read csv files from a directory into RDD")
            val rddFromFile = spark_file.sparkContext.textFile("point.csv")
            println(rddFromFile.getClass)

            def customF(str: String): String = {
                val lat = str.split('|')(2).toDouble;
                val long = str.split('|')(3).toDouble;
                val point = st_makePoint(long, lat)
                val test = rf.where(st_intersects(rf_geometry(col("proj_raster")), point))
        .select(rf_value_at_point(rf_extent(col("proj_raster")), rf_tile(col("proj_raster")), point) as "value")
                return test.toString()
            }
            val rdd2=rddFromFile.map(f=> customF(f))
            rdd2.foreach(t=>println(t))
            spark.stop()

      }
    }
```

when I'm running getting null pointer exception, any help appreciated

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedPlan(Dataset.scala:3416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.filter(Dataset.scala:1490)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.where(Dataset.scala:1518)
    at main.scala.sample.SparkSQLExample$.main$scala$sample$SparkSQLExample$$customF$1(SparkSQLExample.scala:49)
```

Comment: Don't use `return` in Scala. Like ever. It doesn't do what you think it does. When you `map` to `customF` it returns from the entire `map`. Dont think that's the main issue but remove that return and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

The function which is being mapped over the RDD (`customF`) is not null safe. Try calling `customF(null)` and see what happens. If it throws an exception, then you will have to make sure that `rddFromFile` doesn't contain any null/missing values.

It is a little hard to tell if that is exactly where issue is. I think the stack trace of the exception is less helpful than usual because the function is being run in a spark tasks on the workers.

If that is the issue, you could rewrite `customF` to handle the case where `str` is null or change the parameter type to `Option[String]` (and tweak the logic accordingly).

By the way, the same thing allies for UDFs. They need to either

1. Accept `Option` types as input
2. Handle the case where each arg is `null` or
3. Only be applied to data with no missing values.